# Dockerize and reuse NodeJS dependency

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm developing an application based on a microfrontend architecture, and in a production environment, the goal is to have each microfrontend as a dockerized NodeJS application.

Right now, each microfrontend depends on an internal NPM package developed by the company, and I would like to know if it's possible to have that dependency as an independent image, where each microfrontend would, some how, reuse it instead of installing it multiple times (one for each microfrontend)?

I've been making some tests, and I've managed to dockerize the internal dependency, but haven't been able to make it reachable to the microfrontends? I was hopping that there was a way to set it up on `package.json`, something similar to how it's made for [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths), but since the image's scope are isolated, they can't find out where's that dependency.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a Node-level package dependency, it really should be listed in the `package.json` file.  The library itself isn't the sort of standalone executable that's a good match for packaging in a Docker image, and it's not good practice to have an undeclared dependency that you have to know to `npm install` separately.

Comment: I see what you mean @DavidMaze and it makes sense. Each microfrontend should be able to run in its own isolated scope, but confuses me having to install the same dependency (which is a bit heavy) several times, one for each microfrontend. Do you have any suggestions on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 solutions to your question

1. create a package and import it in every project (see [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) for local npm registry)
2. Use a single Docker image with shared node_modules and change command in docker-compose

**Solution 2**
Basically the idea is to put all your microservices into a single Docker image In a structure like this:

```
/service1
/service2
/service3
/node_modules
/package.json
```

Then on your docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: my-image:<version or latest>
    command: npm run service1:start
    environment:
      ...
  service2:
    image: my-image:<version or latest>
    command: npm run service2:start
    environment:
      ...
  service3:
    image: my-image:<version or latest>
    command: npm run service3:start
    environment:
      ...
```

The advantage is that you now you have a single image to deploy in production and all the shared code is in one place

Comment: Thanks @R4ncid for you responde. In terms of local npm registry, we've been using Nexus. About using a single Docker image with shared node_modules, can you describe a little more? I've been able to create a Docker image this the shared dependency, but can't be accessed from the other microfrontend Docker images.